# Flask - AJAX fetches NONE value request.args.get

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, flask

My python code returns error :

> TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'NoneType'

Ajax is able to load the data from my html file and sends the request.
My python code doesn't receives the value.

My AJAX code

```
$(function() {
$("#forgot").submit(function(event) {
     var em = document.getElementById('email').value;
     var ph = document.getElementById('phone_number').value;
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $SCRIPT_ROOT + "/forgot_password",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            'email' : em,
            'phone' : ph

        }),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("hi");
            if(data.status == "success")
            { alert("Your password has been sent to your registered email"); }
            else{
                 alert("Invalid Credentials");
            }
        },
         error:function(exception){
            alert(exception);
            console.log('Exeption:'+exception);
            }
    });
});
});
```

My server code :

```
@app.route('/forgot_password', methods=["GET","POST"])
def forgot_password():
form = LoginForm()
if request.method == "POST":
    _email = json.loads(request.form.get('email'))
    _phone = json.loads(request.form.get('phone'))
    print(_email['value'])
    print(_phone)
    check_email = User.query.filter_by(email=_email,phone=_phone).first()
    if (check_email != None):
        return(jsonify({"status":"success"}))
    else :
        return(jsonify({"status":"fail"}))
return(jsonify({"status":"fail"}))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is you are trying to get `GET` values instea of getting `POST` value.
Your code should look like `request.form['email']` not `request.form.get('email')`
 because your XMLHttpRequest is `POST`**not** `GET`.